# How can I copy an array values and not a reference in java?

Tags: java, arrays, reference, copy

I am trying to copy values of array `tempo` to `newPosition` but `newPosition` keeps changing when `tempo` is changed by the method `getObjectPosition()`. Here is my code.

```
private int[] newPosition = new int[2];
private int[] oldPosition = new int[2];
private int[] tempo = new int[2];
private int  theId, objectSpeed
private boolean threadInitialized = false;

while(this.getObjectMagnitude() > 0)    {

        tempo = this.getObjectPosition();

        if(!this.notification)  {
            System.out.println("Hostile Object Identified! Tracking in progress.....");
            Arrays.fill(this.onOffSwitch,false);
            investigatePatterns.submit(analyseFutures);
            this.notification = true;
        }

        if(this.init_pos)   {

            this.newPosition = this.tempo.clone();
            this.newAndOldTime[1] = System.currentTimeMillis();
            this.init_pos = false;
        }
        else if(!this.init_pos) {

            System.out.println(this.newPosition[0]+"," +this.newPosition[1]+" and "+
                    this.tempo[0] + "," + this.tempo[1] 
                    );

            if(!(Arrays.equals(this.newPosition, this.getObjectPosition())))    {    //do other stuff }
        }
 }
```

I also tried other methods like `System.arraycopy()` and implementing a `for` loop but none worked.

And here is the `getObjectPosition` method

```
private int[] getObjectPosition()   {
    return MainThread.theObject[this.theId].getPosition();
}
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
I am now using this loop. It works

```
    private static int[] fullCopy(int[] source) {
    int[] destination = new int[source.length];
    String e, f, g = "0";

    for(int i=0; i< source.length; i++) {
    f = Integer.toString(source[i]);    
    for(int k=0; k<f.length();k++)
    {
        for(int h=0; h<10; h++) {
        e = Integer.toString(h);
            if((f.charAt(k)) == (e.charAt(0)))
                g = g + (e.charAt(0));
        }
    }
    destination[i] =Integer.valueOf(g);
    g = "0";
    }
    return destination;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Array.clone copies references to the array so any change to one element in the array will result in a change to the corresponding reference of the other array. What you are trying to do is copy the values of the array. To do this I would recommend creating a loop to go through each index in the the A array and assign it to the same index in the B array.

Also as a side note for Boolean conditionals you do not need to have

```
if(bool == true)
```

You can instead do

```
if(bool)
```

And for checking for a false value do

```
if(!bool)
```

Example of System.arraycopy:

```
void runExample(){                                                                           

//show before                                                                            
printArrays();                                                                           

//copy array values                                                                      
System.arraycopy(originalArray, 0, copiedArray, 0, originalArray.length);                

//show after copy                                                                        
printArrays();                                                                           

//change original values                                                                 
for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++){                                          
    originalArray[i] = i;                                                                
}                                                                                        

//show values after change                                                               
printArrays();
```

}
Results from this are:

original array: 4,2
copied array: 0,0

original array: 4,2
copied array: 4,2

original array: 0,1
copied array: 4,2

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. I read a lot of articles about deep copying an array, I didn't find a descent one that simply explains the concept.

Comment: I updated my comment to show System.arraycopy(), this will copy values instead of copying references. If you're still having trouble can you show examples of how you're implementing the arraycopy() and/or the for loop?